# Using turtlebot_create drivers with Roomba 500 series

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am attempting my first implementation of SLAM and am trying to decide on a platform. Since I live outside of the US the Create is not available to me.

I saw in [this thread](http://answers.ros.org/question/27755/roomba-500-series-installation-problem/) that it was possible to patch the create drivers from the turtlebot for use with the 500 series. Unfortunately the links they provide are dead.

Would performing the patch myself be too ambitious for an amateur?

The other option is to use [these drivers](https://github.com/Arkapravo/roomba_500_ROS_drivers), which I would need to port from Fuerte to Hydro.

Can someone provide a scale of difficulty for either of these tasks? I am reading [this thread](http://answers.ros.org/question/120431/is-it-possible-to-use-fuerte-packages-in-hydro/) which makes the latter option seem reasonable. I just feel there may be circumstances I am unprepared for. I have a timeline of about three months so I would like to have an idea before spending $300.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/195986/using-turtlebot_create-drivers-with-roomba-500-series/) by [kinect_guy](https://answers.ros.org/users/20330/kinect_guy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 38 on 2014-10-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on 2014-10-27**:
What about the Kobuki platform? It is supported by ROS and it is the standard platform for Turtlebot 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

All of the information I was referencing is outdated. The TurtleBot stack now fully supports the Roomba 500 series; the proper variables just need to be exported.

---

Originally posted by [kinect_guy](https://answers.ros.org/users/20330/kinect_guy/) with karma: 38 on 2015-04-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [oscillative](https://answers.ros.org/users/20785/oscillative/) on 2015-05-06**:
Did you get the roomba and turtlebot create to work together?  Which model of roomba did you have?

**Comment by [kinect_guy](https://answers.ros.org/users/20330/kinect_guy/) on 2015-05-06**:
Yes I did. I am using the 560.

**Comment by [oscillative](https://answers.ros.org/users/20785/oscillative/) on 2015-05-07**:
thanks!!!!